# How to modify a formula to suit this application

Tags: transpose

I have an problem that I am unsure how to solve.

Hopefully someone can edit this question to get the fancy equations up as I don't know how.

I have a formula to find a variable, say $$a = \frac{(b * c)} {d}$$

Now if d = 1000 but due to my application in software (its a long story), I cannot divide by 1000 but I can divide by a number in the range of 2^n, say 2,4,8,16...1024, basically so I can shift right to divide. So,

How can I modify the above equation so that d = 1024 instead of 1000 and still get the correct answer?

Hope I made this clear, if not I will edit my question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is quite a detailed MathJax tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It goes into more detailed than needed for your question, but is good to know! :)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide some more context. Are $b$ and $c$ integers? The answer is probably not an integer - how is it represented? Dividing by $1024$ instead of $1000$ introduces an error of about $2.4\%$ - can you live with that? I think we need to know more of the "long story". And do use mathjax as @SamT says.

Comment: $\frac{b c}{1000}=\frac{b c x}{1024}$ if $x=1.024$. You can multiply $b$ or $c$ by $1.024$

Comment: Thanks for your comments on the mathjax, it is easy to use

Comment: @Raffaele Ah that was obvious, thank you. If you want a leave a formal answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{b c}{1000}=\frac{b c x}{1024}$ if $x=1.024$. You can multiply $b$ or $c$ by $1.024$

Comment: Thank you Raffaele!

Comment: Glad this works for the OP. I thought of it but wondered if the context allowed it. Once you allow floating point arithmetic you have to think a bit to know whether left shifts divide by $2$.